# php action method: how to redirect the user input to userinput+required extension?

Tags: php, html, css, google-web-designer

I am using a php code to redirect my control to a know page

```
<form action="abc.html" autocomplete="on", method="post">
What to you want to become?:<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
```

I want to change the abc.html name basing on the user input. If the user enter xyz, after clicking submit, user should be redirected to xyz.html.

Is there any nice way to do it other than php if it is not possible?

thanks

Comment: You could use Javascript instead for this, or have a short PHP script as the endpoint for the form that conditionally redirects to one of those pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with vanilla JavaScript.

1. Give an ID to the form:

   `<form id="myform" action="abc.html" autocomplete="on" method="post" onsubmit="return myfunction(this.id)">`
2. Then in JavaScript define the function `myfunction()` to direct user to specified page:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function myfunction(id) {
   var fname = document.getElementByName('fname').value;
   if(fname=="xyz") {
       document.getElementById(id).action = "xyz.html";
       return true;
   }
   return true; // submit form anyways
   </script>
   ```

Now entering `xyz` in the input the form will go to xyz.html

Comment: Thanks a ton @Shahsani. I don't know javascript. where should i write the javascript file? how should I name it? where should I save it? Can you please help with these

Comment: Place the function `myfunction()` inside `<script>   </script>` tag

Comment: should we save this with any extension? also where should I use this script tag ? in point 1 or point 2?

Comment: Put the script tag inside your HTML document. Better it be in the end of the document before the `</body></html>` tags